Family-centric role playing games
I wonder whether there are any family-centric role playing games, out there.
In these games, each of husband and spouse has a job, and, you can choose to be one or the other during the game, or any one of the children that go to school. You can select to take turns to being one or the other.
Your job in the game is to do stuff according to profession, to push on, life, and be well and be happy while doing tasks, that earn you a living and keep you on schedule.
This, is
Because there are too many games out there, where you do things on your own
And too little, where
You do things together
Or with your family
For, a, joint outcome
(joint family efforts for joint outcomes).
The game, could model all the social and work interactions, of the family, you choose.
Where can I find such a game?
Thank you for your development.
Thank you for your support.
Thanks.
